# Trilinear Interpolation 1820: error: -215:Assertion failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I received this opencv error `1820: error: (-215:Assertion failed)` when developing some Trilinear Interpolation Code

I'm trying to figure out what it means.

I'm also currently wondering if my coding methodology is correct for Trilinear.

Also,  is there a way to get the flow algorithm to work in colour 
    instead of grayscale?  I tried in colour, but received a similar error.

Three Frames for download here

1. [Frame 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm1aunl9iyury1w/3325_71.png?dl=0)
2. [Frame 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryq1inide2ef3e0/3325_72.png?dl=0)
3. [Frame 3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/icvworeiee9ueaq/3325_73.png?dl=0)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy as sp

Image1_Fp = ".\\3325_71.png" to 
Image2_Fp = ".\\3325_72.png" to 
Image3_Fp = ".\\3325_73.png" to 

Write_Image_Location_Tri_Sampled = ".\\3325_syn_Tri.png"

def imread(filename):
    im = cv2.imread(filename)
    return im

if __name__ == '__main__':

    im1 = imread(Image1_Fp)
    im2 = imread(Image2_Fp)
    im3 = imread(Image3_Fp)

    im3gray = cv2.cvtColor(im3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im1gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(im1gray, im3gray, flow=1, pyr_scale=0.5, levels=2, winsize=10, iterations=5, poly_n=7, poly_sigma=1.2, flags=0)

    # Trilinear Interpolation using meshgrid and remap
    half_flow = 0.5 * flow # reduce the flow lines all by half.
    h, w = flow.shape[:2]
    grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(h, w) # Identifies the coordinates of the grid with x, and y value,
    coor_x_1 = grid_x + half_flow[:, :, 0] # So the flow is a displacement, and you need to add the pixel location to it to get where that displacement came from on the grid
    coor_y_1 = grid_y + half_flow[:, :, 1]

    # Finds the interpolated intensity from the pixels closest to the flow line from RGB Image 1
    output_1 = cv2.remap(im1, coor_x_1, coor_y_1, cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode =cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    coor_x_2 = grid_x - half_flow[:, :, 0]
    coor_y_2 = grid_y - half_flow[:, :, 1]

    # Finds the interpolated intensity from the pixels closest to the flow line from RGB Image 2
    output_2 = cv2.remap(im2, coor_x_2, coor_y_2, cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode =cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # combined half of each
    Combined_Output = (output_1 / 2) + (output_2 / 2) # Applies Trilinear part for a synthesized batch

    cv2.imwrite(Write_Image_Location_Tri_Sampled, Combined_Output)
```

I am expecting to see a synthesized image that looks similar to the one in-between the two images, but I receive this error.

```
Exception has occurred: error
OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:1820: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ((map1.type() == CV_32FC2 || map1.type() == CV_16SC2) && map2.empty()) || (map1.type() == CV_32FC1 && map2.type() == CV_32FC1) in function 'cv::remap'

File "..\OpenCVOpticalFLowAndTrilinearInterp.py", line 90, in <module>
    output_1 = cv2.remap(im1, coor_x_1, coor_y_1, cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode =cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue?